# How to Extract Just The Postal code without entering the google maps URL in the address bar

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=16.539311299999998,80.5820222

which outputs the data I needed.

how can i extract just the postal code from that json array, i dont want the google maps url to be typed in the address bar.

how can i use javascipt to get the data without having that url in address bar

i want the zipcode from the URL
HOW?

please help me with this.

[Please check the below image, you will understand the clear picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTot8.png)

Comment: This is an object, you can just go through it and get what you need. What did you try?

Comment: Im noob, i want to extract the postal code, without entering the google maps url into the address bar.

Comment: var latlng = "16.539311299999998,80.5820222";
var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latlng + "&sensor=false";
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    for(var i=0;i<data.results.length;i++) {
        var adress = data.results[i].formatted_address;
        alert(adress);
    }
});

Comment: That's hard to read, could you edit it into your question and explain why it didnt do what you wanted?

Comment: As the first step have a look at Google's example about reverse geocoding in Maps JavaScript API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse